# RestKit: RKClient not recognized by Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, rest, restkit

I am using/implementing **RestKit** into my project at the moment, and I've followed the github wiki to install everything correctly. Everything is there and working properly. The application builds and runs great. I'm just trying to make a HTTP GET request now by first setting up the `RKClient`, but my project doesn't seem to recognize `RKClient` even though I've imported the `<RestKit/Restkit.h>` file in the header of the file.

I'm beginning to think that the `RKClient` class is deprecated or something because every other class seems to be there as expected.

I've tried looking everywhere and really ensuring that I've followed the instructions to setup **RestKit** properly, and yet I'm still stuck on the first line!! (Initializing the `RKClient`).

Another possibility is that I'm doing this all wrong. I just implemented the library, so I'm just playing around with it. But if I'm not doing a HTTP GET request the right way, please guide me the right direction.

Thanks!!

Comment: what is the RestKit version ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From RestKit 0.20.x onwards RKClient is not part of  RestKit. You can use HTTP Client like :

```
   [RKObjectManager myObjManager].HTTPClient
```

See This [Link](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0)